# Is there an app that creates a "virtual computer screen" in a window? (I want to maximize iOS apps in it)

Tags: ios, window-manager, apple-silicon

iOS apps on the Mac M1 can only be maximized or tiled left to right. I was thinking, if you can create a "virtual computer screen" and "maximize" an iOS app in there and resize the "virtual computer screen" to your liking, then you can resize any iOS app on the M1 however you'd like!

Perhaps there is certain tiling software that is capable of this?

I'm currently looking into Moom.

Edit: Moom doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way of "forcing" iOS apps to actually resize to your liking in that manner or any other manner.

You can "zoom" apps - meaning that the graphics will just be stretched or zoomed (pixel-doubled for example). You'll not be able to see more text, more images or anything like that in the app. It will just be the same content - but stretched or zoomed.