# Is there a way to force fullscreen on apps that have fixed screen sizes? or to define screen size when launching the app?

Tags: applescript, fullscreen

Can be done on windows by making a shortcut for a program and adding something like " -screen-width 1920 -screen-height 1080 -screen-fullscreen 1" to target in properties, looking for way to force something like this on macos

tried apple script from here, [Set size of window to exact pixels, and place via x, y coordinates](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98064/set-size-of-window-to-exact-pixels-and-place-via-x-y-coordinates)
only seems to work on apps that can already be resized

Comment: What would you expect to happen then? If the applications is written for a window size of 640x480, what does it help to force it to be fullscreen? It probably won't make use of the additional space.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/426691/is-there-an-app-that-creates-a-virtual-computer-screen-in-a-window-i-want-to